# smartwatch that advertises bluetooth LE

Tags: bluetooth, localization, bluetooth-lowenergy, sony-smartwatch

I'm planning to replace the Beacon tag of my Bluetooth (BLE)-based localization System with a smartwatch. Therefore, the smartwatch has to be able to advertise bluetooth signals. However I can't find any information about smartwatches using BLE advertising methods. I actually don't want to use an additional smartphone which would be able to advertise. I already found that the iWatch and the Moto 360 are probably not able to advertise.

Does anyone know if there's (or will be) a smartwatch available that is able to advertise BLE signals?

Thanks a lot!
el Baum

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is not possible for Sony Smartwatch atleast. This is because in order to be able to broadcast a BLE advertisement of your choosing, any given Android device has to be able to support [BluetoothAdapter.isMultipleAdvertisementSupported()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#isMultipleAdvertisementSupported()). Unfortunately, this feature is not available on most Android Wear devices.

If your Android device does support multiple advertisement, then you can create an advertisement packet and use the [BluetoothLeAdvertiser](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getBluetoothLeAdvertiser()) object to start advertising.